# Copy/Paste storage in Linux

Tags: linux

Where and how is copied information stored on Linux systems? By copied information I mean `[right click]` --> `Copy` / `CTRL+c`.

I believe this is a feature of the Desktop Environment, so it might be different from DE to DE.

For example if I wanted to make a system administration application and I would allow to show some history of what has been copied, would I then need to read from a file? Or run a command?
This is hypothetically. I just want to learn more about Linux systems in general.

Comment: .. I am losing the will to live

Comment: Why would you say that, @ed-heal?

Comment: @TroelsSørensen Because it's called a clipboard. Do you know what stack in stackoverflow.com refers to?

Comment: @Secko I never thought about it, but I assume it's the stack - as in stack trace. The word clipboard evidently didn't come to mind in my search for an answer. Brainfart maybe? Thanks for your comment. It was way more helpful than the one from Ed Heal.

Comment: @TroelsSørensen No, that is just an operation that is done with stack. Stack is a portion of memory reserved or allocated for your programs variables and other data. Stack overflow is something that happens to stack when it's assigned pointer reaches out of bounds. It tries to allocate memory beyond it's scope (stack bounds). So the program actually uses memory which is not assigned to it, resulting in it's crash. Hope this helps. (Håper dette hjelper deg. Ha det bra!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the environment. Cut and paste within an application may be handled by the application. Cut and paste between applications is more often handled by the X Windows Clipboard - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is a **clipboard history manager**. There are many managers out there for different desktop environments; this [page on the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/clipboard)
 lists several of them.

Answer (score 0):

This (handling of clipboard and selection) is defined in the [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html) specification (and also [ICCCM](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/)). Most toolkits ([Qt](http://qt-project.org/), [Gtk](http://gtk.org/), [FOX](http://fox-toolkit.org/), [FLTK](http://fltk.org/), ...) handle this somehow. It uses atoms and selection inside the [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) server and [its protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) (and [selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection)). Details are boringly complex, so trust some toolkit doing it.

In practice it is well standardized, this is why you can run a Qt or KDE application on a Gnome desktop, or a GTK application on a KDE desktop.